# How to update an sql table with values from another table when there is no clear column to join on?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have two tables; One with information about players which contains a column for SchoolName. Another with information about the schools with contains columns School (the official school name) and Nickname(of the school name).

I want to update the players table such that for each player, there is a SchoolName column which uses the official school name from the schools table and a nickname column which uses the nickname from schools.

The issue is that the players table contains schools that sometimes matches to schools.School, sometimes to schools.Nickname, sometimes to neither because of differences in spelling/wording.

For example, for a player in players, the SchoolName is 'Millersville' which would match to the row in schools where the official name and nickname are 'Millersville University of Pennsylvania' and 'Marauders'.

For a different row in players, the SchoolName is 'Arizona' which could either match to 'Arizona State University', nickname 'Arizona State' or 'University of Arizona', nickname 'Arizona'.

I've come up with this query that most accurately matches the two tables by the school names but now I'm not sure how to update the players table with the correct school names.

```
SELECT Player
     , SchoolName
     , School
     , Nickname
  FROM schools
         , players
 WHERE players.SchoolName = schools.School

        OR players.SchoolName = schools.Nickname
        OR schools.School LIKE CONCAT('%', lower(trim(SchoolName)), '%')
    AND lower(substring_index(trim(SchoolName), ' ', 1)) = lower(substring_index(trim(School), ' ', 1))
    ));
```

This is what I was thinking for transforming this query into an Update statement but I don't know how to do it correctly or what to join on since there is no clear column that matches for every row.

```
UPDATE players 
INNER JOIN schools ON (SELECT ....)
SET SchoolName = schools.School
SchoolNickname = schools.Nickname;
```

Comment: Why are choosing not to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
UPDATE players p JOIN
       school s
       ON p.SchoolName = s.Nickname OR
          (s.School LIKE CONCAT('%', lower(trim(p.SchoolName)), '%') AND
           lower(substring_index(trim(p.SchoolName), ' ', 1)) = lower(substring_index(trim(s.School), ' ', 1)))
          );
    SET p.SchoolName = s.School
WHERE
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this fully, but it should be something similar to this.

```
UPDATE players p
    LEFT JOIN schools s1 ON p.SchoolName = s1.School
    LEFT JOIN schools s2 ON p.SchoolName = s2.Nickname
SET players.SchoolName = COALESCE(s1.School, s2.School)
players.SchoolNickname = COALESCE(s1.Nickname, s2.Nickname)
```

In short, if you aren't sure which field, you can join to the same table twice using different joins. Then you can use coalesce to figure out the join that worked.

Comment: Odd, yes, but it works. Elsewhere you will be writing a sub select for each row you are trying to update.

Comment: If that is true then presumably answers that don't employ LEFT JOIN are wrong?

Comment: There is more than one way to do almost anything in SQL. It is more what is more efficient and what works best for a particular situation.

Comment: So your contention is that your method is more efficient?